# Best approach to keep checking account type in Django

Tags: django

I have a project about school system which has 3 types of users
`Staff`, `Student`, and `Lecturer`.

The url config for user of type `Staff` will have a url like `.com/staff/ something/something`. For example: `.com/staff/account-management`
Similarly, `.com/student/something/something` for `Student` users and `.com/lecturer/` for `Lecturers`.

If a student accesses a `Staff` user's webpage or its similar urls, such as `.com/staff/account-management` or `.com/staff/resources-management`, I want to display a webpage saying **You do not have the permission to access this page**

In conclusion, a user of a type cannot access the urls of another user type.

Also, everytime I load a `student` webpage, I need the first name and full name, as well as the classes enrolled.
For `lecturer` webpage, i need the first name and full name, and the classes the lecturer teaches.
For `staff` webpage, i only need the first name and full name.
this is for the base.html purpose that is extended by other templates
this base.html contains navigation bar that needs these info

This is my approach:

In the student `views.py`, there is a view called `check_user` and `student_homepage`

```
check_user(request)
   user = request.user
   std = Student.objects.filter(user=user).first()
   if std is not None :
      get all of the classes he is currently studying and put it in class_display
      context = {'role' : 'STUDENT', 'f_name' : user.first_name, 'l_name' : user.last_name, 'class_display' = class_display}
      return context 
   else:
      check if the user is an Employee object
      if it is an Employee object,
          check if it is a staff or a lecturer
          if it is a staff, 
              context = {'role' : 'STAFF', 'f_name' : user.first_name, 
              'l_name' : user.last_name, msg='You are not authorized to see 
              this page'}
          if it is a lecturer,
              get all the classes he is currently teaching and put it in 
              class_display
              context = {'role' = 'LECTURER', 'f_name' : user.first_name, 
              'l_name' : user.last_name, msg='You are not authorized to see 
              this page','class_display = class_display}
          if it is not student or employee
               context = {'role' = 'none', msg='Unidentified account 
                type','class_display = class_display}
```

`errorpage.html` extends the base.html, `errorpage.html` has a button for the `lecturer/administrative` to go back to their `homepage` after reading the error message.

```
student_homepage(request)
user_dictionary = check_user(request)
if user_dict['role'] == 'STUDENT'
    return render(request, student_homepage.html, user_dictionary)
else if role is staff 
    return render(request, staff/errorpage.html, user_dictionary)
else if role is lecturer
     return render(request, lecturer/errorpage.html, user_dictionary)
```

Well this works but it seems like a bad approach because for every student view that renders a student page, I must check the role of the user. Is there a way to write it only once but it will work for all url starting with .com/student? i have a view for the url .com/student that initially will redirect to the student homepage but i think it is only called if i go to .com/student.

Comment: one recommanded is `decorator`, another resource is [Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Comment: @tim I've read on decorators, and I think what I want is similar to user_passes_test except that it seems it has only 2 possibilities: if true, return to the view and false redirect to another page. I would like to have 3 possibilities as the page for lecturer, student, and administrative are different. Can you give me more hints pls? Should i make a custom decorator?

Comment: yes, definatelly a custome one, or set different permissions for different users, i.e. `student permission` ...